Stucco in need of repair?
We recently had our cement tile roof replaced with asphalt shingles, and along the bottom edge of the stucco wall (where it meets the roof), it looks sort of unfinished. Is this an issue? If so, what’s a good remedy?



You should have the stucco cut back, install a flashing like you have on the timber above to overlap the shingles and the refinish the stucco.

+1, yes. There is supposed to be a "Z flashing" or "step flashing" there.
